# White space renders shrinked in email sent from SMTP client

Tags: c#, email, outlook, smtpclient

I'm sending emails from an SMTPClient as follows:

```
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage
    {
        To = "Test",
        Subject = "Subject",
        Body = "Body"
    };

    var smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

It generates an .eml file with the following content:

> X-Sender: admin@localhost
>   X-Receiver: admin@localhost
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   From: admin@localhost
>   To: admin@localhost
>   Date: 23 Apr 2020 12:46:27 +1000
>   Subject: TestSubject Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=us-ascii
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> ```
> Field:   Value1=0D=0AField_a: Value2=0D=0A
> ```

Inside the body I'm using spaces to layout text on multiple lines so they align. However when I open the generated email in outlook the spaces render shrinked and the alignment gets thrown off.

If I copy the text from the email into Notepad it renders OK. If I save the email anew from Outlook it renders OK.

Is there a way to configure the email to so that the white space characters render the same width as other letters?

Comment: The font is different or Monitor settings are different on two machine that are causing the alignment issue.

Answer (score 0):

The email was set to render in plain-text and so Outlook used its default font which in my case wasn't monospaced and so letters had varying widths.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also find that Outlook tends to remove what it considers to be extra line breaks.

A better approach is to send your e-mail as HTML with the `<pre>` tag.

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage
{
    To = "Test",
    Subject = "Subject",
    Body = "<pre>Body</pre>",
    IsBodyHtml = true;
};
```